# configparser() issue in python with IDE Microsoft Code

Tags: python-3.x

Specs: Python version 3.7.3 (64-bit)
IDE Microsoft Code (latest edition as of 4/23)

Background I am having issues with executing my code with Configparser only on Microsoft code. I installed other IDE's pycharm etc and I do not have any issues. I prefer Microsoft Code interface / debugging so I would prefer to keep using it. I even went an extra step and installed MS-Code on another server and tried to exec my code with the exact same issue. On a side note if you execute the code in debug mode in ms-code it works without a key error.

This issue is really confusing to me and any help would be appreciated

Current structure of Configparser in code

```
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('api_config.ini')

#Reads in each of the api URLs to use from the config file
line_item_reporting = config['apis']['line_item_reporting']
line_item_meta = config['apis']['line_item_meta']
package_reporting = config['apis']['package_reporting']
package_meta = config['apis']['package_meta']
io_meta = config['apis']['io_meta']
io_reporting = config['apis']['io_reporting']
```

Error code
   line_item_reporting = config['apis']['line_item_reporting']
   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\configparser.py", line 958, in **getitem**
   raise KeyError(key)
   KeyError: 'apis'

api_config.ini

```
[general]
meta_pull=50
num_loops=10
index_start=0
index_end=20
password=#######
lookback_window=3

[apis]
io_reporting = https://some_url
line_item_reporting = https://some_url
line_item_meta = https://some_url
package_reporting = https://some_url
package_meta = https://some_url
io_meta = https://some_url
```

Comment: I found that if i add the full pathway in MS-Code for the api_config file it works. However I am still confused why all of the other IDE's and even MS-Code begugger does not require the full path. I assume the issue is based on the file location vs the python installation but it should be the same as I only have 1 python installation installed 1 version.

Comment: I have the solution just not the why which to me is the most important.

Solution is taken from Jean-François Fabre

conf_file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)),'api_config.ini')
The above code adds a direct path between tools.py and the file location.